# How to get current user's username with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

So far I've been looking all over the interwebs and the Meteor docs but nothing has been working for me.

I am creating an account with

```
Accounts.createUser({
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: password
});
```

And I know that is working since `{{#if currentUser}}` is working.

However, I am trying to get the current logged-in user's username with something such as

```
var username = Meteor.userId();
console.log(username);

var username = Meteor.userId().username;
console.log(username);
```

But neither is working, when I use `Meteor.userId()` I just get a random(I'm guessing encrypted) string of numbers and letters, and when I use `Meteor.userId().username` it says it's undefined.

All help is welcome and sorry for my possibly terrible grammar, It's **very** late here!

Answer (score 11):

`Meteor.userId()` returns the _id of the user from the [Mongo.users](https://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) collection. That's why it looks like a meaningless string.

You want [`Meteor.user()`](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-user). The [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/accounts) are your best friend :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried that already. It returns as undefined.

Comment: Clarification: Just "Meteor.user()" returns with Object {_id: "2zWQoT7wWWhnXEWjY", emails: Array[1]}. But "Meteor.user().username" returns with undefined.

Comment: Does your login provider set a username? `accounts-password` doesn't, Twitter does.

Comment: I mentioned in the OP what I used for the Username. "Accounts.createUser" has a username option which I used.

Comment: This does **not** work for me. as `console.log(Meteor.userId(), Meteor.user());` outputs `wN9vCjAAQ6S9YB7Ad undefined`.

Answer (score 11):

Try with `{{currentUser.username}}`

Comment: i have used this code and my username is showing now. but when i use this below code its not showing email address. that is 

{{currentUser.email}}

i am logged in by username not email it username is showing but email is not showing.

Comment: @Pritesh share the code with others.They helped you

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `username: Meteor.user()` in the .js file
and in the html file use `{{username.profile.name}}`

Comment: This is the correct version if you are using OAuth (e.g. Facebook or Google login)! See [the docs](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#current-user) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing it like this:

1. Include an accounts package: meteor add accounts-password
2. import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
3. console.log('Username: ' + Meteor.user().username);

User needs to be logged in, else Meteor.user() returns null.

Edit: Also keep in mind Meteor.user() will not be available until the users collection is sinced to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Accounts.createUser -> username will set up only Meteor.user().profile.name. And if you want to have Meteor.user().username you should probably use also Accounts.onCreateUser ( https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser ) and add username field like:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {

    user.username = user.profile.name;

    return user;

});
```

It is that way because Meteor.user().username is a custom field in this case.

Answer (score 1):

add to clients js

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
});
```

Comment: Thx, very helpful. This was all I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

All in One!

```
 Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: Meteor.userId() }).username
```

Then you can either returned value to variable, State or Session ..etc

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.userId();
```

This code above return a string that is the unique ID of the logged user Meteor.userId() not the whole user object. So you can not attempt to any property .
To have the current username do as following:
1 - /  In meteor controller

```
var uniqueID = Meteor.userId(); 
var username = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: uniqueID}).usename;
```

2 - /   In meteor template

```
{{ currentUser.username }}
```